# Linux 10.04 configure default site on webserver

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, web-server

I am trying to figure out what determines the "default" website on a webserver.

I am running a Ubuntu 10.04 webserver that hosts 5 different websites.

In my apache2/sites-available folder there is an entry like this for each of the 5 sites:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mysite.ca
ServerAlias www.mysite.ca
ServerAdmin daniel@mysite.ca
DocumentRoot /home/sites/Dropbox/mysite.ca/
  <Directory /home/sites/Dropbox/mysite.ca/>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to access this webserver via IP address from a computer that is behind the firewall and within Active Directory, the webpage for one of the sites loads, but I would prefer to load a different site. How can I control which site loads by default on my webserver?

Answer (score 1):

It loads the first available `VirtualHost` which is simple the order they are placed in your configuration file. You can check the order by typing `apache2ctl -S` on the commandline of your server.

To change this, you can re-order the `VirtualHost` container, or simply create some sort of "default".

Answer (score 1):

Usually on my installs I add a file named 00_Default_Site on the /etc/apache2/sites-available/ and add the Default Vhost config on it.

As soon as you don't add any other config file that could have precedence on a name sorting, it will always be the first config file to be included, and because that, the first to load and the one that will behave as default.

Comment: Thanks @Leon.  I want to try your suggestion, but I'm still a little unclear where to begin.  Could you help explain a bit more?  I made the entry that you suggested, but it is not working.  Do I need to restart anything after making the entry?

Comment: ok, I just did `$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` to restart the server and now it is partially working.  Now I am getting the right site to load, but it is not loading the CSS.  Weird.

Comment: Did you remembered to activate the site?
Try a "sudo a2nsite 00_Default_Site" and it should be enabled.

Comment: Thanks again @Leon.  I think there was a typo in your code.  It should be a2ensite, you were missing the 'e'.  That being said, when I ran the code it told me that the site is already enabled.  The site loads for me, but doesn't load any CSS or JS.  Wish I knew why.